# Facebook Request for App Review. How to enable "Submit for Review" button

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, android-facebook

I implemented a Facebook Login feature for an Android app. When trying to execute my Facebook login implementation (after upgrading some Google and Facebook libraries to make it work), I was getting this error message:

[image]

For that reason, I proceeded to try to submit my app to Facebook requesting an App Review. I generated the latest `.apk` and I am ready to submit my app for review. The blocker that I am experiencing is that the button "Submit for Review" is disabled, as you see in the image below:

[image]

The answer might seem obvious: "Add permissions or features to continue" and the button will be enabled. But when I click the link "Add additional permissions and features", I already have listed and approved the only two permissions or features that I want for now:

[image]

What do I need to do to enable the "Submit for Review" button?